# How to handle overlapping geofences on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, overlapping, geofencing

I am building a geofencing app on Windows Phone. The current version includes about 100 geofences, some of the overlap with others. I wrote a background task and set the trigger the entered state of a geofence. When I am out, testing my app, it occurs, that the background task does not react on geofences which overlap with others.

This is the code from the backround task:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var reports = GeofenceMonitor.Current.ReadReports();
    var report = reports.FirstOrDefault(r => (r.Geofence.Id == "testID") && (r.NewState == GeofenceState.Entered));

if (report == null) return;

var toastXmlContent = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

var txtNodes = toastXmlContent.GetElementsByTagName("text");
txtNodes[0].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode("Geofence entered!"));
txtNodes[1].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode(report.Geofence.Id));

var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXmlContent);
var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
toastNotifier.Show(toast);
```

}

Does anybody know, how to handle overlapping geofences on Windows Phone?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried removing the where Id == "testId" and just getting notified for all fences?

Comment: yes, I already tried it. It seems that the problem is that the background task is not fired that regularly to check if the phone's location is within a new geofence.